# Building a Shunt active power filter in the synchronous reference frame

Tags: matlab, active-filter, shunt, simulink

This schema representing a shunt active power filter in the synchronous reference frame, I'm focusing on the Area in the red box !

**Schema**

[image: Schema]

I want to learn how to build my own shunt active power filter in the synchronous reference frame **from scratch**, i understood pretty much the method behind it, but i am stack within Simulink, i followed the steps of the Algorithm one by one :

1. Get the load's current (scope : I_Load)
2. Clark Tranforation (scope : ab_Frame)
3. PLL Gives the SinW/CosW (scope : PLL)
4. Park transformation (scope : dq_Frame)
5. **Extraction of the Harmonics currents (i* d & i* q)**
6. Back from dq_Frame to ab_Frame (Park Inv)
7. Back from ab_Frame to abc_Frame (Clark Inv)

**Simulink Model :**

[image: Simulink Model]

I'm stack at step 5 (The blue box)
Now that i have `I_load` in the `dq frame`,

**How can i extract the compensation current i* d and i* q from iq_Load and id_Load ?**

**what is the simplest way to do that ? (in the schema up, they use an FTJ (the Orange box), what is that ? some also put LPF ( at 2*pi*50) why ?)**

Scopes :

**I_Load Scope**
[image: I_Load Scope]

**ab_Frame Scope**
[image: ab_Frame Scope]

**PLL Scope**
[image: PLL Scope]

**dq_Frame Scope**
[image: dq_Frame Scope]

Comment: What a post .I hope somebody understands it .

Comment: Try making the question more accessible.

Comment: i tried to edit it ! would you please consider taking a look now, Thank you.

Comment: @Andyaka could you please take a look now

Comment: Had a look and didn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as usual, I'm answering my own question,

The block i was looking for is a LPF : [Low Pass Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter).

The idea is that we have both the Harmonics and the fundamental together and we need to separate the two, so we push P (total power) through LPF tuned at the frequency of the grid (fundamental 50/60 Hz), it will let pass only the fundamental component Pf, than we subtract the total from the fundamental, it will leave us only with the harmonic component.